# получить позицию строки по сортировке

Tags: mysql, база-данных

В таблице у каждой стройки есть уникальный текст(id), можно отсортировать строки по разным значениям, как получить расположение строки относительно сортировки (ORDER BY)? То есть например если я сделаю ORDER BY всей таблицы по SCORE, то строка будет на 15 месте. Как получить это же значение(15) одной командой(SELECT * FROM table where id="12345")

Comment: `select count(1) from table where score <= X` правда с равенством могут быть проблемы, если у вас несколько строк с одинаковым score. требуется уникальный ключ сортировки

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,score,
  @rownum := @rownum + 1 as row_number
from test1111
cross join (select @rownum := 0) r
order by score desc
```

Здесь данный вопрос уже решен https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566695/select-increment-counter-in-mysql